# Center align images

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I've been trying to center align these images but they just won't go. I've trying messing around with the sizing and the left-align but nothing works. What do I do?

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4uGtq/embedded/result/

```
left-align:50%; /* Doesn't work */
```

Comment: Align them with what? Looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#icon-wrapper a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
}
```

The width and height are necessary in this case because you have the images absolutely positioned. If you didn't have the width and height, everything would kind of fall in on itself.

Answer (score 0):

When I try your demo (in Chrome) the images *are* center aligned as a group as long as I don't resize the browser to more than 1300 pixels wide. So given that you have a bunch of `@media only screen` rules for different `max-width` and the highest number you go up to is `(max-width: 1300px)` that behaviour makes sense doesnt it?

Change this line:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
```

to this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
```

and it should fix it as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/4uGtq/6/embedded/result/